# How do you call a C# function with overloaded return arguments from MATLAB?

Tags: c#, matlab

Suppose I have the following code in C#:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyFunction(out string str)
    {
        str = "Hello";
    }

    public void MyFunction(out int a)
    {
        a = 5;
    }
}
```

Suppose I want to call this function from MATLAB:

```
>>NET.addAssembly('MyCSharpDll.dll');
>>obj = myNamespace.MyClass();
>>number = MyFunction(obj);
```

Evidently `MyFunction` is an ambiguous call. How can I tell MATLAB which overloaded function to call?

Comment: There are multiple errors in this code. First, use "class" keyword before class name. Second, type names are wrong, use either string and int or System.String and System.Int32 - these are equivalent. Third, if you use return don't mark return type as void, but as either of the above. And then you get to the point that function cannot differ by return types only, so you have to change either name or parameters. That's before getting to Matlab calls...

Comment: Thanks. You say that function cannot differ by return types only. But when declared as 'out'? I've got exactly the situation above in a C# API. It compiles..

Comment: The methods in the code above differ in the parameter list, not in the return type. Both methods have `void` return type. Although the parameter is an "out parameter", it is still part of the argument list, and not the return type.

Comment: Interesting ... so far the object truly has the two methods (`z = metaclass(obj); m = findobj(z.MethodList, 'Name', 'MyFunction')` returns `m` as a 2x1 method array that have correct `OutputNames` in signatures) ... Unfortunatly i did not find any solution to make dynamic invocation on correct method from these metadata ... :(